# how to make designable textfield code class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibdesignable

I am a beginner in programming and in iOS development. I want to make a swift file that contains a code to make Designable textfield, so I will not edit the UI element display by coding, all the UI that will be edited, I will edit it in Interface builder.

[image]

I need to input an image in UITextfield, and I follow along a tutorial in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjXOUd4hI6U&t=932s to put an image in the left side of the UITextField, like the lock image in the picture above. here is the the to do this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable


class DesignableTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var leftImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var leftPadding : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusOfField : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadiusOfField
        }
    }



    func updateView() {
        if let image = leftImage {
            leftViewMode = .always

            // assigning image
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: leftPadding, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            imageView.image = image

            var width = leftPadding + 20

            if borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.none || borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.line {
                width += 5
            }

            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 20)) // has 5 point higher in width in imageView
            view.addSubview(imageView)


            leftView = view

        } else {
            // image is nill
            leftViewMode = .never
        }
    }



}
```

but now I need add another image on the right side only and both of them (i.e on the the right side AND left side). how do I edit those code? I have tried but it doesn't appear and to be honest I little bit confused to adjust the x and y coordinate of the view. I need your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions for this

The **First solution** is the easiest one. You can have a view and insert inside the view a `UIImageView`, `UITextField`, `UIImageView`. Add constraints to set the desired sizes. You can make the text field transparent. With this method, you can customize it how you want.

The **Second solution** is how you are doing it.

The first thing you need to do is add the properties to the right image and right padding. Under the left padding property add the following code:

```
 @IBInspectable var rightImage : UIImage? {
    didSet {
      updateRightView()
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var rightPadding : CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      updateRightView()
    }
  }
```

With this new properties, you can choose the image and edit the x location.

After the update function create a new function called updateRigthView

Like this:

```
    func updateRightView() {
    if let image = rightImage {
      rightViewMode = .always

      // assigning image
      let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: rightPadding, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
      imageView.image = image

      var width = rightPadding - 20

      if borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.none || borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.line {
        width -= 5
      }

      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 20)) // has 5 point higher in width in imageView
      view.addSubview(imageView)


      rightView = view

    } else {
      // image is nill
      rightViewMode = .never
    }
  }
```

You had to edit the right properties.Now head to storyboard and try it out. To move the image to the left decrease the right padding 0,-1,-2,-3, etc. To move the image to the right increase the right padding 0,1,2,3.