# how to insert image in the left AND right to textfield using @IBDesignable in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable

I am a beginner, I am trying to make a password textfield with two image, one on the left side (lock image) and another one on the right side to reveal the password like this one
[image]

[image]

but my senior ordered me to make it in the @IBDesignable class of text field so the main code stay clear from UI. i find something similar thread about this in here [how to make designable textfield code class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676046/how-to-make-designable-textfield-code-class-in-swift)

but it seems that the code is for left image only or right image only,  i need both of them (lock and eyes symbol) appear in the textfield. I have tried to modify the code there, but i can't achieve what i need. really need your help, maybe you have done this in your previous project :)

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable


class DesignableTextField: UITextField {

@IBInspectable var rightImage : UIImage? {
    didSet {
      updateRightView()
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var rightPadding : CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
      updateRightView()
    }
  }

    @IBInspectable var leftImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var leftPadding : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadiusOfField : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadiusOfField
        }
    }



    func updateView() {
        if let image = leftImage {
            leftViewMode = .always

            // assigning image
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: leftPadding, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            imageView.image = image

            var width = leftPadding + 20

            if borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.none || borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.line {
                width += 5
            }

            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 20)) // has 5 point higher in width in imageView
            view.addSubview(imageView)


            leftView = view

        } else {
            // image is nill
            leftViewMode = .never
        }
    }

func updateRightView() {
    if let image = rightImage {
      rightViewMode = .always

      // assigning image
      let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: rightPadding, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
      imageView.image = image

      var width = rightPadding - 20

      if borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.none || borderStyle == UITextBorderStyle.line {
        width -= 5
      }

      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 20)) // has 5 point higher in width in imageView
      view.addSubview(imageView)


      rightView = view

    } else {
      // image is nill
      rightViewMode = .never
    }
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code:

```
@IBInspectable var leftSideImage:UIImage = UIImage() {

    didSet {
        leftView = UIImageView.init(image: leftSideImage)
        leftViewMode = .always
    }
}

@IBInspectable var rightSideImage:UIImage = UIImage() {

    didSet {
        rightView = UIImageView.init(image: rightSideImage)
        rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way you can do, In storyboard add a button and add constraints as follows

1. Button trailing edge = textfield trailing edge
2. Button (vertical) centre = textfield (vertical) centre
3. give fix height and width to button

same you can do in right side.
Button leading edge = textfield leading edge

[]_______________[]